# How do I send data to an element with a certain ID using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rgraph

I am using WebSockets to receive a packet of data that needs to be sent to two different `canvas`es with IDs called `magnitude1` and `magnitude2`. There are graphs being drawn on these `canvas`es, and I am looking to refresh the graphs with new data periodically. However, when I call the function that sends the data to the correct element, my console shows that data is getting sent to `magnitude1` once, `magnitude2` once, and then data only gets sent to `magnitude1` for refreshing. Here is my code:

```
dataCollector.onmessage = function(evt)
{
        console.log("onmessage is being called");
        var realData = new Float32Array(evt.data); //data is expected in the format [nodeID,(256 floats)]
        setInterval(function(){readMagPacket(realData);},1000);
}

function readMagPacket(theGoods)
{
    var nodeID = theGoods[0];
    console.log("The node ID is " + nodeID);
    var magnitude = new Array();
    for(var i = 1; i < theGoods.length; i++)
    {
            magnitude[i-1] = theGoods[i];
    }

   console.log("The length of packet " + nodeID + " is " + magnitude.length);

   graphMagnitude(magnitude,nodeY,freqRange);

   Mag(magnitude,nodeID,freqRange);
}

function Mag(magnitude,index,freqRange)
{
    console.log("Mag is called");

    var magPlot = new RGraph.Bar('magnitude'+index,magnitude);

    magPlot.Set('labels',freqRange);
    magPlot.Set('gutter.left',100);
    magPlot.Set('gutter.bottom',40);
    magPlot.Set('ymax',.01);
    magPlot.Set('ymin',0);
    magPlot.Set('backgroun.grid',true);
    magPlot.Set('numyticks',2);
    magPlot.Set('title','Magnitude of Channel ' + index);
    magPlot.Set('title.yaxis','Magnitude (dB)');
    magPlot.Set('title.xaxis','Frequency (MHz)');
    magPlot.Set('title.xaxis.pos',.2);
    magPlot.Set('title.yaxis.pos',.5);
    magPlot.Set('background.color','white');
    magPlot.Set('colors',['green']);
    magPlot.Set('hmargin',.00001);

    magPlot.Draw();
}
```

Some more detail: I want to get the packets through the socket as floats and store them in `realData`. I want to pass this to a function which separates the `nodeID`, which is the first number in the packet, from the rest of the data. I will use this to figure out which `canvas` to send the data to. In the line `var magPlot = new RGraph.Bar('magnitude'+index,magnitude);`, I pass in the `nodeID` as `index`. The part of the constructor that says `'magnitude' + index` should determine the `id` of the `canvas` in which I want to create the graph. I think this is where the error is. I want to be able to refresh both graphs by combining `setInterval`, `readMagPacket`, and `Mag`, but it only seems to be refreshing `magnitude1` only. When I looked at my console to see what was going on, I saw that all the packets were sent across first and then `readMagPacket` was called afterwards. Ideally, I'd like `readMagPacket` to be called on each packet that comes through. Is there any way to fix the code to make that happen?

Comment: Why are you using setInterval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling readMagPacket repeatedly with the same data when each packet arrives. I believe it will work as you want if you remove the setInterval call, and call readMagPacket directly.